# How to bind an array data to a table created in html in C#

Tags: c#

Iam creating a table in .cshtml. I have to transfer the data from table to .cs in array. Now I have to initialize the table data from .cs..

```
<tr>
<td> <input class="form-control " id="Description0" title="Description" name="BS_Model.Description[0]" style="text-align:left;width:100%" type="text"></td>
</tr>

public string[] Description { get { return disc; } set { disc = value; } }

Description = new string[] { "Test" };
```

Now I want the data "Test" in the table.

Comment: What project is this? Asp.net mvc, web form, console+html file, etc...?

Comment: Yes Asp.net mvc, web form,

Comment: ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET WebForms are two mutually exclusive technologies.

Answer (score 0):

## MVC Razor

To display the contents of the array in a table using Asp.Net MVC and razor syntax, use a for loop and iterate through your array, adding a row (or column) at each iteration:

```
@{ 
    string[] Description = new string[] { "Test" };
}

<table>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Description.Length; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Description[i]</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

## Web Forms

In Asp.Net Web Forms, you can bind an array to a ListView in the code behind:

**Code Behind**

```
string[] Description = new string[] { "Test" };
listViewDescription.DataSource = Description;
listViewDescription.DataBind();
```

**ASPX File**

```
<table>
    <asp:ListView ID="listViewDescription" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                     <%# Container.DataItem %>
                 </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</table>
```